# Image showing in local dev but not on Heroku

Tags: backbone.js, heroku

I have a small `Backbone` app.  In my navbar I have an image. Here is the code:

```
  <a href="#" >
    <img src="../app/img/isxLogo.png" width="56" class="navbar-brand">
  </a>
```

This shows up fine when I am in developement.  When I push to `Heroku`, I get a `404` not found error.

```
Request URL:http://intense-zzzzzz-1111.herokuapp.com/app/img/isxLogo.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What could be causing the `404`?  Why would the image be found in `dev` but not when I push to `Heroku`?

**Image now showing**

I changed the path to `/img/isxLogo.png` and it will now show in `Heroku`, but it does not show in my dev environment.  Why does the path change?  How would you show the image in both environments?

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine, the root directory set by your web server must be set to the directory above where you app is.

Change the URL to `/app/img/isxLogo.png` and it should work.

What are you using to serve the app locally?

I would recommend using the same web server/method locally if you aren't already to avoid any surprises like this :)

Comment: I tried that and it only worked in dev.  I got a `404` from the app on `Heroku`.  Here was the url that `Heroku` was looking at: `http://intense-zzzzzz-1111.herokuapp.com/app/img/isxLogo.png`.  The url for which the image is found on `Heroku` is : `http://intense-zzzzzz-1111.herokuapp.com/img/isxLogo.png`

Comment: What are you using to serve the app locally?

Comment: I am just serving it with `express`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not very familiar with node and express. Can you show me the command you're using?